# New-item "Illegal Characters in path" when I use a Variable that contains a here string

Tags: string, powershell, path, powershell-5.0, new-item

```
foreach ($Target in $TargetUSBs)
{
$LogPath= @"
$SourceUSB\$(((Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_volume)|where {$_.DriveType -eq "2" -and $_.DriveLetter -eq $Target}).SerialNumber)_
$(((Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).LocalDateTime).Year)$(((Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).LocalDateTime).Month)
$(((Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).LocalDateTime).Day)_$(((Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).LocalDateTime).Hour)
$(((Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).LocalDateTime).Minute)$(((Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).LocalDateTime).Second).txt
"@

    $LogPath = $LogPath.Replace("`n","").Trim()
    New-item -Path "$LogPath"
}
```

The Irony is when I copy and paste the contents of my variable and manually create a new-item -path and paste said contents it works but when I use the variable it does not...
Brief summary of my goal I am taking a USB labelled ORIGINAL and obtaining the S/N of every USB plugged in at the time and creating separate log files for each with the title consisting of SERIALNUMBER_DATE_TIME.txt and these files are created in ORIGINAL USB

`$LogPath` contains for example the following: `E:\Mattel\1949721369_2018912_93427.txt`
Yet when I use the Variable in New-item it indicates `"Illegal characters in Path"`

FYI `$LogPath` is a `System.String` not an object
`$TargetUSBs` is filled with all USB drives plugged into the system

this method of using a variable for a path usually works fine for me only difference is the here-string I used this time around does this cause my problem? I hope not because I really don't want to fill that variable all on one line. `New-Item's` helpfiles shows `<String[]>` for `-path` parameter does this mean I have to use a string array? and if so how do I convert this to make this work?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `LOW LINE` (underscore) at the end of the first line of the here variable?

Comment: If I do that my format no longer is SerialNumber_Date_Time it just becomes SerialNumberDate_Time which is an issue with the naming convention I was asked to stick too :( It also still generates the same error fyi

Comment: @lit thank you for cleaning up my code section in my question btw how did you this? I couldn't figure out how to work past the escape char at the ….$LogPath.Replace("`n"," ") part

Comment: While editing the question, select the block of code and use the `{}` icon to format it.

Comment: @lit Thank you for your help! I will keep this in mind for future questions :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that Windows uses `CRLF` line endings (Unix only `LF`), so you still have `CR` chars in your path.

To fix this just use:

```
.Replace("`r`n","")
```

---

However you can easily simplify your code so you do not require the messy here-string or replace/trim...

By using a single [`Get-Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date) call you can format it to your desired output. This means you can just build the `Path` as a simple string and involves much less code:

```
foreach ($Target in $TargetUSBs)
{
    $SerialNumber = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_volume | where {$_.DriveType -eq "2" -and $_.DriveLetter -eq $Target} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SerialNumber
    $DateTime = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMd_Hms"

    New-item -Path "$SourceUSB\$SerialNumber_$DateTime.txt"
}
```

Comment: I would use the format `"yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"` as this has leading zeros (`20180903` vs `201893`) so your names will sort correctly in order.

Comment: FYI .Replace`("`r`n","")`worked with my code so ty for this just working on trying your version next!

Comment: you make a great point there will add this :) that said the alternative method your suggested isn't quite working for somer eason the serial number isn't ending up in the path?? It just creates this `New-item : The file 'E:\Mattel\20180912_105903.txt' already exists.` over and over again which then ofcourse errors due to these being made in the same second

Comment: Fixed it your method had a small error `New-item -Path "$SourceUSB\$($SerialNumber)_$DateTime.txt"` I added the `$()` around `$SerialNumber` as variable wasn't being interpreted properly